# iframe src function call is continuously getting triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am facing an issue with iframe src where i am calling a function which binds me the return value

Here is the code

```
<div  class="collapse" class="col-xs-6" ng-if="setFrame">
<iframe width="100%" height="650px" ng-src="{{getIframeSrc()}}" ></iframe>
```

And controller code is like

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.controller('topicsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, getCandidateInterviewListService, searchBoxService, iterateArray) 
    angular.forEach($stateParams.candidateDetails, function(value, key) {
        if (value.name == $stateParams.name) {
            $scope.file = value.filepath;
        }
        $scope.setFrame=true;
    });
    $scope.getIframeSrc = function() {
        var filepath='http://localhost:4000/' + $scope.file;
        return filepath
    };
```

But here the function getIframeSrc is getting triggered continuously as like a loop

I dont understand whats happening here

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: inside your `$scope.getIframeSrc` function do console.log for your **filepath**  and check the path

Comment: I am getting the correct path @MohanGopi

Comment: `console.log( $scope.getIframeSrc());`  try this and check

Answer (score 1):

It is called in a loop because the engine checks for changes the whole time.
Everytime your function is run something changes and so it becomes a "loop".

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mjkyke2/45/)

HTML

```
<div  class="collapse" class="col-xs-6" ng-if="setFrame">
<iframe width="100%" height="650px" ng-src="{{iframeSrc}}" ></iframe>
```

JS

```
$scope.iframeSrc = 'http://localhost:4000/' + $scope.file;
```

Comment: but here i could able to display iframe content @KRONWALLED

Comment: I could able to see the src correctly in inpect element but unable to load the file

Comment: My bad. I think you have to inject `$sce` and set it like `$scope.iframeSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:4000/' + $scope.file);`

Comment: still it is the same :(

Comment: i have already included 
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
            'self',
            'http://localhost:4000/**'
        ]);

in .config

Comment: Added a JSFiddle for you. Works as intended.
If it does not work: Do you have a same origin policy or something configured on your webserver?

Comment: Yes i m using CORS

Comment: Hey its working the problem was i used $event.stopPropogation() to the child div to trigger ng-click action but if i remove $event.stopPropogation() im getting iframe content but if i keep it again it is not getting loaded